# NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 adding an extra day on

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have a method that updates a label and acts as a stop watch. It works fine accept when I format the string to factor days in it adds an additional day on. 
For example. If the stopwatch is started ten minutes ago the label will display: 
01:00:10:00

 it should just display 
 00:00:10:00

```
    - (void)updateTimer
{
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *dateValue=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"pickStart"];

    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:dateValue];

    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];

    // Create a date formatter
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd:HH:mm:ss"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];

    // Format the elapsed time and set it to the label
    NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
    self.stopWatchLabel.text = timeString;

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing isn't appropriate. Your goal seems to be to convert `timeInterval` into days, hours, minutes, and seconds. Your use of `timerDate` and `NSDateFormatter` are not the proper way to achieve that goal.

`timeInterval` is not an offset from January 1, 1970 and `timeInterval` doesn't represent a date.

What you should do is get the difference between `currentDate` and `dateValue` as a set of `NSDateComponents`.

```
- (void)updateTimer {
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *dateValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"pickStart"];

    unsigned int unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:unitFlags fromDate:dateValue  toDate:currentDate  options:0];
    int days = [comps day];
    int hours = [comps hours];
    int minutes = [comps minutes];
    int seconds = [comps seconds];

    NSString *timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d:%02d:%02d", days, hours, minutes, seconds];
    self.stopWatchLabel.text = timeString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks rmaddy! I managed to get my final answer from your solution. Good work

Answer (score 0):

There is no "additional day", the "date" you produce is a point in time after the 1st Jan 1970, so if your format includes the day you get at least a 1...

Just stick with the `NSTimeInterval` value and use `NSDateComponentsFormatter` - which also formats time intervals despite the name - or just do the math yourself to get the seconds, minutes, etc. and format those.

HTH

Comment: Of course you can have a time interval of -10 minutes and you'l get Dec 31st 1969 at 23:50:00.

Comment: @gnasher729 - of course ;-) I maybe should have said "relative to" rather than "after", but I did say "you produce" so it is correct as stands (by fluke of course :-))